# Why doesn't the Android Studio launch an error when I pass a var of MutableList<File> to List<File> in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

The paramter `videoList` in Code B is `List<File>` type, and the var `listFile` is `MutableList<File>` in Code A.

I think Code A will cause an error, but in fact, it works well, why?

**Code A**

```
private lateinit var listFile: MutableList<File>


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)     

        val outputDirectoryOfVideo = getVideoOutputDirectory(requireContext())
        listFile =outputDirectoryOfVideo.listFiles{file -> VIDEO_EXTENSION_WHITELIST.contains(file.extension.toUpperCase())}
                   .sorted().reversed().toMutableList()

        videoRecyclerView.layoutManager =  LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
        val aVideoListAdapter=VideoListAdapter(listFile,requireActivity())
        videoRecyclerView.adapter=aVideoListAdapter        
}
```

**Code B**

```
class VideoListAdapter (private val videoList: List<File>, private val mActivity: Activity) : RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoListAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Subtypes

[`MutableList<E>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/index.html) is a subtype of `List<E>` (`E` can be any type, including `File`).

```
interface MutableList<E> : List<E>, MutableCollection<E>
```

That means a mutable list can do anything (and be used anywhere) that a list can.

### Bonus: Variance

The list interface is actually declared as `List<out E>`. That means the interface only ever returns (*produces*) objects of type E, and never receives (*consumes*) them. Since normally we can return a subtype in place of its supertype, `out` let's us do this:

```
// This works
// - List<E> is a producer (covariant in E)
// - List<String> can fulfill all members of List<CharSequence>
val listStrings: List<String> = mutableListOf<String>("Some", "example", "Strings")
val listCharSeqs : List<CharSequence> = listStrings // use List<Strings> as List<CharSequence>

// This does NOT work
// - MutableList<E> is a producer AND consumer (invariant in E)
// - MutableList<String> cannot fulfill add(element: CharSequence)
val mutableListStrings: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf<String>("Some", "example", "Strings")
val mutableListCharSeqs : MutableList<CharSequence> = mutableListStrings // does not compile
```

...or more relevant to your question:

```
class Video {...}
class TvShow : Video {...}
class Movie : Video {...}

class Adapter(private val inputOnly: List<out Video>) {...}

val justMovies: MutableList<Movie> = mutableListOf(...)
val adapter = Adapter(justMovies) // this is ok!
```

You can read more here (including `in` for contravariance, star projections, and constraints): https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html